# What effect does adding ".default" to a configuration setting of a VScode extension in package.json have?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking at a VScode extension sample and find the `configuration` section of `package.json` has some settings that contain `.default`.

I noticed that I cannot read these settings using `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myext').get('scale');`, while `.get('updateOnSave')` does work.

```json
"configuration": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "myext.default.scale": {
                    "markdownDescription": "Default zoom level.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "auto"
                },
                "myext.updateOnSave": {
                    "markdownDescription": "Update preview when saving",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                }
            }
        }
```

- When would I use `.default`?
- How can I read these settings?

Comment: to get that setting call `.getConfiguration('myext').get('default.scale');` There is not a real use for this. Just mention the default value of the setting in the `default` property. If you want to temporarily change the zoom level, don't write the setting back to the configuration, use a command like `Save zoom setting as default`

Comment: Thanks. Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about this `.default` naming of the setting variable.

To get that setting call `.getConfiguration('myext').get('default.scale');`

There is not a real use for this. Just mention the default value of the setting in the `default` property in `package.json`. If you want to temporarily change the zoom level, don't write the setting back to the global or workspace or folder `settings.json`.

To store the current zoom for the next start of VSC use a command like `Save zoom setting as default`.

To get back to the factory default (`default` property in `package.json`) just remove the setting from the `settings.json` file.